# Problema con retorno de carro en PHP

Tags: php

tengo un problema al escribir en un fichero de texto que cuando aplico el \n no pasa a la siguiente linea y me deja todo el texto pegado, aquí el código.

```
$Data = "Nombre " . $jsonencode[0]->nombre . "\n" . $jsonencode[0]->
apellidos . "\n". $jsonencode[0]->email;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que el salto de línea podría variar según la plataforma, lo mejor sería usar la constante predefinida `PHP_EOL`.

> [Imprime] el símbolo 'Fin De Línea' correcto de la plataforma en uso.
>   Disponible desde PHP 5.0.2
>
> <sub>[Constantes predifinidas](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.constants.php) en el Manual de PHP</sub>

De ese modo delegas a PHP que use el salto de línea adecuado según la plataforma donde se ejecute el programa.

El código quedaría así:

```
$Data = "Nombre " . $jsonencode[0]->nombre .PHP_EOL. $jsonencode[0]->
apellidos . PHP_EOL. $jsonencode[0]->email;
```

Haciendo eso, no tendrás que preocuparte de si funcionará en unas plataformas y en otras no.

La única restricción es que funciona a partir de PHP 5.0.2. En caso de tener una versión anterior, podrías implementar una función en la que se pregunte por el sistema operativo/plataforma y en función de eso decida qué salto de línea usar.

Comment: Vale, asi es, muchas gracias @A. Cedano

Answer (score 2):

Diferentes sistemas operativos utilizan diferentes convenciones para los saltos de línea, Windows por ejemplo, utiliza "\r\n",y en los sistemas unix se utiliza "\n". Por lo tanto, si estás trabajando sobre Windows puedes probar con sustituir el "\n" por "\r\n". Para más detalles, revisa la sección de [notas](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) de la documentación.

Comment: yo uso Windows 10 y el salto de línea me funciona con \n y con \r\n http://php.net/manual/es/function.echo.php

Comment: depende mucho de con que lo leas al archivo, notepad por ejemplo recién hace poco lo soporta https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/05/08/extended-eol-in-notepad/